# Error occurred during execution of ‘Server Heartbeat’-Load Balance

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, recurring, hangfire

I have the following :
- 2 web servers running in a load balanced setup.
- Each of these can enqueue Recurring Jobs with the following code in OwinStartup.cs :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("ConnectionString")
                .UseFilter(new LogFailureAttribute());
            app.UseHangfireServer();

 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Job", () =>FunctionTrigger(), Cron.Daily(5, 0));
```

The FunctionTrigger is a simple function using Stateless Transaction session to insert records into the Database.

So when am using one Server the jobs running successfully, But in load balance an error happens and no records inserted into the DB .

This is the log error:

```
Hangfire.Server.ServerHeartbeat - Error occurred during execution of 'Server Heartbeat' component. Execution will be retried (attempt 2 of 2147483647) in 00:00:03 seconds.
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.GetConnection()
at Hangfire.Server.ServerHeartbeat.Execute(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryServerComponentWrapper.ExecuteWithAutomaticRetry(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am using Hangfire 1.4.5

**Is this because the job runs tow times on each server ?! how can i avoid that. ?! **
Thanks.

Comment: Any Comments  on the above?

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue and after some search , I found this discussion on the [hangfire discussion](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/batching-hundreds-of-jobs-causes-connection-pool-timeout/2360), the error is occured for the Hangfire versions < 1.6.4 .
The issue have been fixed on the 1.6.4 [release](https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/08/30/hangfire.1.6.4.html).
Hope that can help you if you still having the issue.